# Application classloader instance per war?

Tags: java, static, classloader

If i have two wars under tomcat webapp, i believe these will be loaded by separate instance of application classloader. Is that correct ?
Also are static variables are stored per application classloader ?

**Update:-**
Here is the output in common class used by both war files(test1 and test2)

```
 ClassLoader loader = MyCustomClass.class.getClassLoader()
```

l

```
loader is WebappClassLoader
  context: /test1
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@3839029b


loader is WebappClassLoader
  context: /test2
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@3839029b
```

Then i printed the System.identityHashCode(loader )

It returns different web classloader but same parent which i believe is system or common class loader . Right ?

Comment: Why don't you experiment? What happens when you print the classloader of the same application class in two separate webapps? What happens when you modify the static value of a static field in one app, and print it in the other? Why don't you read the documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: JB Nizet Thanks. I got good data points from even your comments. Please see my update

Comment: JB Nizet i actually asked this question in context of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241780/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-class-exists-under-tomcat-lib  where my war is not able to find the class even after putting it tomcat_home/lib folder

Comment: Well, I would leave this jar in the webapp, where it belongs. The whole point of having separate class loaders for the classes of each webapp is to be able to have different versions of the same classes in several webapps, and to make sure one webapp doesn't mess with the state of another one.

Comment: Actually its singleton cache which i want to share across applications

Comment: @JBNizet but i am not sure why my webapp not  getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when i place the jar under `tomcat/lib`

Comment: It would help if you posted the **entire** stack trace in your other question.

Comment: @JB Nizet i have added entire stack trace.  Please see now . Same thing is repeated in stack trace. which is too large. If it does not help i will attach complete file on some file upload service and post a link