# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : when class exists under tomcat/lib?

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, ehcache

I have two wars both using one specific jar (`ehcache-core.jar`). I did put the jar under `<Tomcat_Home>\lib`.
But when I start the server, my application throws below error  where class exists under `ehcache-core.jar`

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#1' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/enrollment-1.5.jar!/META-INF/spring/enrollment-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'applicationService1' while setting bean property 'arguments' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationService1': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tesing.plan.service.PlanService com.tesing.enrollment.service.ApplicationServiceImpl.planService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'planService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.tesing.plan.orm.dao.PlanPremiumRateLookupDAO com.tesing.plan.service.PlanServiceImpl.planPremiumRateLookupDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'planPremiumRateLookupDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/plan-management-1.5.jar!/META-INF/spring/plan-management-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.tesing.utils.picklistprovider.PickListProvider com.tesing.utils.web.action.BaseController.pickListProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryBasedPickListProvider' defined in file [F:\codeBase_all\codeBase_Custom\applications\customer-portal\target\customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\picklist-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryBasedPickListProvider' defined in file [F:\codeBase_all\codeBase_Custom\applications\customer-portal\target\customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\picklist-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/codeBase_all/codeBase_Custom/applications/customer-portal/target/customer-webapp-public-1.0-Snapshot/WEB-INF/lib/co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar!/META-INF/cgi-spring/utils/util-services-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.getAdvice(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.isAspectJAdvice(AspectJProxyUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.makeAdvisorChainAspectJCapableIfNecessary(AspectJProxyUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.extendAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying:

> Could not **initialize** class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager

Check further back in the logfile, and there should be a stacktrace for some exception that was thrown during the initialization of `CacheManager` or one of its dependent classes.  Fix the cause of that exception, and this problem will be solved as well.

Comment: i have pasted the relevant logs. To me looks like application is not able to find `CacheManager` class because as soon as i copy the jar in `app_home\web-inf-lib` error goes away

Comment: any suggestion on my comments